# Is Brain a Quantum Computer

Tags: brain

I read somewhere that brain is a quantum computer and is actually capable of accessing multiverse. Is this possible?

Comment: This is not a forum. Take that in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) if you like but this is not a worldbuilding question.

Comment: It is very possible that you read that. People write a lot of stuff.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Some aspects of the brain functioning show quantum effects. Tunneling, for instance, in synaptic behavior. There is some similarity between quantum computer techniques and the human brain. For instance, the human intuitive brain uses probability processing techniques to make decisions, and some optimization algorithms (if they can even be called algorithms in quantum computing - quantum computers are definitely NOT Turing machines).  If one did a lot of handwaving, one could posit a connection between entanglement and ESP, especially between family members. But alas no qbits in the brain.

Comment: Perhaps an edit might be 'What aspects of quantum computing might be useful in a sentient brain?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably read that on the huffpost. It's the first result when I typed your question.
And because it's a huffpost and it's clickbait it's "close to the thing that is similar to truth".

The thing is that as quantum mechanics can have two states "at once" and so can your brain have two opinions on one topic at once, from what type of flavour of ice cream you want, to the answer if there is a god or not. So not physics extrapolate that "those two things are like one another" and they arrive at resolution "brain is like quantum computer".

To quote astrophysics during Conference of Polish Physicists during "quantum Technologies" sessions: Human brain is a supercomputer. But most people prefer to run Pong.